# PCM to AAC conversion using mediacodec

Tags: android, pcm, aac

I am using a media codec class in Android (Jelly Bean) to encode PCM format to AAC. The file was encoded but no music player is able to play that file. I was not able to find any working code or proper documentation on the net.

This is my code:

```
public void doConvert()
{

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            try
            {
                int codecCount = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();

                for ( int i=0; i < codecCount; i++)
                {
                    MediaCodecInfo info = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
                    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, info.getName());
                    for ( String type : info.getSupportedTypes() )
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, type);
                    }

                }

                File inputFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/Ghajini27_Mono_8Khz.wav");
                //File inputFile = new File( sampleFD.get);
                Log.e("File", String.valueOf(inputFile.length()));
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                fis.skip(44);//remove wav header

                File outputFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/out.m4a");
                if ( outputFile.exists()) outputFile.delete();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                //BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
                MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", 22050, 1);
                outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
             //  outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_MASK, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO);
                outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 22050  );
                outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
                //outputFormat.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, inputFile.length());
                double durationInMs = (inputFile.length()/16000)*1000;
                Log.e("duration",String.valueOf((long)durationInMs));
                outputFormat.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_DURATION, (long)durationInMs );


                codec.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE );
                codec.start();

                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffers();

                boolean hasMoreData = true;   
                MediaCodec.BufferInfo outBuffInfo = new BufferInfo();
                byte readBuffer[] = new byte[48000];
                byte writeBuffer[] = new byte[48000];

                do
                {
                   int nextBuffer = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(5000);
                   Log.e("NextBuffer","nextInputBuffer = "+nextBuffer);

                    if ( nextBuffer >= 0 )
                    {



                        ByteBuffer inBuf = inputBuffers[nextBuffer];
                        inBuf.clear();
                        int bytesRead = fis.read( readBuffer,0, inBuf.capacity() );

                        Log.e("bytesread","Read = "+bytesRead);

                        if ( bytesRead < inBuf.capacity() )
                        {
                            hasMoreData = false;
                        }

                        inBuf.put(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        codec.queueInputBuffer(nextBuffer, 0, bytesRead, 0, hasMoreData?0:MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    }


                    int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer( outBuffInfo, 3000);
                /*    logger.log(Level.INFO,"nextOutputBuffer = "+outputBufferIndex);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"outBuffInfo offset = "+outBuffInfo.offset);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"outBuffInfo size = "+outBuffInfo.size);
                    logger.log(Level.INFO,"outBuffInfo flags = "+outBuffInfo.flags);*/


                    //while ( outputBufferIndex > -1 )
                    //{ 

                        outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex].position(outBuffInfo.offset);
                        outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex].get(writeBuffer,0,outBuffInfo.size);

                        fos.write(writeBuffer,0, outBuffInfo.size);
                      //  logger.log(Level.INFO,"Writing = "+outBuffInfo.size+" bytes");


                        outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex].clear();

                        codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                        if ( outBuffInfo.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM )
                        {
                            codec.flush();
                            codec.stop();
                            codec.release();
                            break;
                        }

                        //outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer( outBuffInfo, 1000 );
                        //logger.log(Level.INFO,"nextOutputBuffer = "+outputBufferIndex);
                    //}

                } while (outBuffInfo.flags != MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

                fis.close();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();



            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
                //Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO, "Codec Error",e);
            }

            //logger.log(Level.INFO,"Done");

            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your code. Otherwise it'll be more or less impossible for other people to figure out what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Encoded file does not have a header its just a raw file

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Comment: @tikson do u have the full correct code that convert pcm raw audio file to aac file format ?

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to choose a container for it. I prefer adts.

Copy the the payload data into an aray that is large enough for your container, just add on your bits. So after scouring the internet for my solution I worked some snippet into place

method 'fillInADTSHeader'

```
    profile =( configParams[0]>>3 )&0x1f;

    frequency_index = (this.configParams[0]&0x7) <<1 | (this.configParams[1]>>7) &0x1;

    channel_config = (this.configParams[1]>>3) &0xf;

    int finallength = encoded_length + 7;       
    ENCodedByteArray[0] = (byte) 0xff;
    ENCodedByteArray[1] = (byte) 0xf1;
    ENCodedByteArray[2] = (byte) ( ((profile - 1) << 6) + (frequency_index << 2) +(channel_config >> 2));
    ENCodedByteArray[3] = (byte) (((channel_config & 0x3) << 6) + (finallength >> 11));
    ENCodedByteArray[4] = (byte)( (finallength & 0x7ff) >> 3);
    ENCodedByteArray[5] = (byte) (((finallength & 7) << 5) + 0x1f) ;
    ENCodedByteArray[6] = (byte) 0xfc;
```

Using something like

```
            byte chunkADTS[]=new byte[info.size + 7];
            fillInADTSHeader(chunkADTS,info.size);
            outputBuffers[bR].get(chunkADTS,7,info.size);
            buffer.pushData(chunkADTS);
```

Should play in shoutcast, etc...

Comment: Would have helped had you defined configParams. As it stands, the developer is left searching for what this is and where it comes from.

Answer (score 3):

There's an android AAC Library
https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc

Try passing your buffers through this library. It might help.

Comment: I tried using this but for the life of me cannot work out how to import it into my project. It is set up as an application as opposed to a library and does not build.

Answer (score 1):

You need a container. Send the encoded output of the MediaCodec to a MediaMuxer. Use mp4 as the container type. No need to use the cryptic code posted by @Andy--S.

Just make sure to give the final file an extension .m4a instead of mp4. MP4 extensions are used for video.

For details on MediaMuxer, see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#writeSampleData(int,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo)