# Using MediaCodec to decode raw AAC audio data works on Android 4.4 but not 4.3

Tags: android, aac, android-mediacodec

I have successfully implemented encoding/decoding raw AAC-LC using MediaCodec.  I'm using the same technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970406/4066415) to encode the data. However, I store the raw AAC data (without headers) and then attach headers on the fly as I pass the data through a MediaCodec decoder.  This all works absolutely perfectly on the Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 both running Android 4.4.  However, on the Galaxy Nexus (running Android 4.3) I get:

```
W/SoftAAC2(1234): AAC decoder returned error 16388, substituting silence
```

Error 16388 means a [decode frame error](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/aac/+/2ddc922da87bb675b8ab8c305566436e806df0d9/libAACdec/include/aacdecoder_lib.h).

I've tried with and without an initial MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG but that doesn't make a difference.

Here is the simplest case (using config packet) to reproduce the error:

```
MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_IS_ADTS, 1); 

byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x11, (byte)0x90};
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", bb);

MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
codec.configure(format, null /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);
codec.start();
ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();

int inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_US);
if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
    ByteBuffer dstBuf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
    byte[] data = {-1, -7, 80, 0, 1, 63, -4, 18, 8}; // values taken from SO answer linked above (chanCfg = 1, packetLen = 9)
    dstBuf.clear();
    dstBuf.put(data);
    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, data.length, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);
}
```

Obviously there is a lot more to the code than this, but this includes all the executed code up to the point of the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to *not* include the ADTS headers.  Both 4.3 and 4.4 support packets without ADTS headers.